# Detectando se um setter de uma propriedade foi chamado

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflexão, .net-core

Olá gostaria de saber se há como descobrir se o valor de uma propriedade foi alterado.

> Exemplo

```
public partial class MinhaClasseExemplo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    public String Telefone { get; set; }
}

var teste = new MinhaClasseExemplo();
teste.Nome = "Hiago";
teste.Telefone = null;
```

No exemplo acima eu defino a classe e instancio o objeto, após isso eu atribuo o valor para o `Nome` e para o `Telefone` (sim coloquei o `null` de propósito). Gostaria de saber via `Reflection` quais `setters` foram chamados, nesse caso o `Nome` e `Telefone` e não o `Id`. Há como fazer isso com `C#`? Preciso de algo assim para deixar uma rotina minha genérica.

Obrigado.

Comment: Apenas como curiosidade e de forma informativa, existe um interface chamada [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2), que é utilizada para monitorar mudanças no estado de um objeto e atualizar clientes (clients), linkados (binding clients) com o objeto, que uma propriedade foi alterado.

Comment: @GabrielHeming top cara!! Isso já ajudava, o que é chato é ter que ficar criando as propriedades privadas =/

Comment: @GabrielHeming cara muito obrigado!!! Ajuda e muito, quer colocar como uma resposta? Assim eu marco ela como correta. Vai me ajudar muitoooo!

Comment: Eu acabei apagando o comentário, mas está ai o link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316417/1628790 .Fiquei na dúvida sobre o .NET core. Implementa ele e veja o resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia amigo,

Andei dando uma pensada e o jeito que eu encontrei foi fazer uma propriedade que vai armazenar essas mudanças e um método para gravar essas informações no `Set` de cada propriedade.

```js
public partial class MinhaClasseExemplo
{
  public int Id
  {
    get
    {
      return this.Id;
    }
    set
    {
      GravaLogPropAlterada(Id);
      this.Id = value;
    }
  }

  public List<string> PropriedadesAlteradas { get; private set; }  = new List<string>();

  public void GravaLogPropAlterada(object property)
  {
    PropriedadesAlteradas.Add((InfoOf(() => property).ToString()));
  }

  static PropertyInfo InfoOf<T>(Expression<Func<T>> ex)
  {
    return (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)ex.Body).Member;
  }
}
```

Seria essa a idéia.

Espero que eu tenha te dado uma luz!

Answer (score 0):

Terá que implementar, obrigatoriamente, no `Setter` a evocação de um método para o que pretende.

Pelo que sei não existe forma de automaticamente perceber se um valor foi alterado sem implementação específica.

O exemplo abaixo está funcional, pode ser que o ajude na sua solução final:

```
public static List<(dynamic classe, string propriedade)> Propriedades { get; set; } =
    new List<(dynamic, string)>();

internal static void AdicionarPropriedade<T>(T classe, string propriedade) where T : class
{
    if (!Propriedades.Contains((classe, propriedade)))
        Propriedades.Add((classe, propriedade));
}

public partial class MinhaClasseExemplo
{
    private string _Nome = string.Empty;
    private string _Telefone = string.Empty;
    private int _Id = 0;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        AdicionarPropriedade(this, name);
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get { return _Id; }
        set
        {
            _Id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }
    public string Nome
    {
        get { return _Nome; }
        set
        {
            _Nome = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Nome");
        }
    }
    public string Telefone
    {
        get { return _Telefone; }
        set
        {
            _Telefone = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Telefone");
        }
    }
}
```

A lista `Propriedades` irá conter tuplos com a instância da classe e o nome das propriedades alteradas. A classe será importante se pretender implementar algo mais genérico com vários tipos de classes.